# Bad Bitlocker implementation

Tags: bitlocker

By mistake, I have encrypted with Bitlocker my data drive (a non-system drive) with the command
`manage-bde -on d: -rk d:`

So the drive was encrypted and RecoveryKey was saved (I assume in the drive's metadata) on this same (encrypted) drive. And now, when the computer reboots Windows asks for the encryption key on USB for that drive. But I don't have it because it was written on this same encrypted drive...

I think the problem is that we haven't turned on automount option. I assume that with automount option on the drive should be available after OS drive is unlocked and OS logon. My question is:

Am I right? If I am - is there any way to turn automount option on without access to Recovery Key? Or any other help?

Comment: Is it not stored in your Micro$oft account? https://account.microsoft.com/devices/recoverykey

Comment: Recovery key is what the name says: a key used to recover the encrypted volume. You got yourself into the chicken-and-egg situation where the recovery key itself is encrypted, therefore inaccessible. Unfortunately it's time to restore your backup.

Comment: Yes I think all data are gone 